# Using facebook's api to monitor new installs on android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to use the facebook api to monitor the conversion rate from facebook ads. On iOS this seems to work. On android I am stuck with an error and I am unable to find a solution. I am using the facebook sdk 3.0.1 version.

the code is simple (took it from the facebook documentation page) in my main activity in onResume i call

```
com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(this, ""+this.getPackageName());
```

but I only get this error:

```
D/ Facebook-publish FacebookException: Install attribution has been disabled on the server.
```

it seems that it is an app configuration related problem. In facebook developer the app is configured the same for iOS and Android:

- Package Name is set correctly
- Class Name is set
- Key Hashes are set and working (tested width facebook login)

In the advanced tab, section Insights both Install Insights and Mobile SDK Insights are enabled.

I also use facebook login and that works without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're calling it wrong. The second argument should be your application ID, not your package name.